# Build aplicação feita com Flask

Tags: python, aplicação-web, flask

Ao executar flash run, recebo o seguinte erro:

> Error: Detected factory 'create_app' in module 'spcdados.app', but
> could not call it without arguments. Use
> "FLASK_APP='spcdados.app:create_app(args)'" to specify arguments.

Minha estrutura é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meus arquivos de config estão da seguinte forma:

```
#app.py
from flask import Flask, abort, url_for, render_template
from spcdados.extensoes import configuration

def minimal_app(**config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    configuration.init_app(app, **config)
    return app
    

def create_app(**config):
    app = minimal_app(**config)
    configuration.load_extensions(app)
    return app

#settings.toml
[default]
DEBUG = false
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///development.db'
TITLE = "SPC DADOS"
SECRET_KEY = "Pocornio2233"
EXTENSIONS = [

    "spcdados.extensoes.appearence:init_app",
    "spcdados.extensoes.database:init_app",
    "spcdados.extensoes.auth:init_app",
    "spcdados.extensoes.admin:init_app",
    "spcdados.extensoes.commands:init_app",
    "spcdados.blueprints.views:init_app",
    "spcdados.blueprints.restapi:init_app"
]
#.env
FLASK_ENV = development 
FLASK_APP = spcdados.app:create_app
```

Não consigo entender onde mais é necessario declarar o FLASK_APP, alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: Onde você rodou `flask run`? Tentou usar `FLASK_APP = app.py`?

Comment: Rodei direto no terminal do visual code, e sim, o flask_app já está definido ali pois estou trabalhando com ele na estrutura da blueprint e factory

Comment: Encontrei o erro, aparentemente é um bug que ainda não foi solucionado com o flask, fiz a modificação do app.py para não receber mais o **config e funcionou =)

Answer (score 0):

Esse é um bug que ainda não foi resolvido no flask, segue debate no git

[Debate sobre o bug em questão](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/4170)

Sendo assim, modifiquei o meu app.py dessa forma

```
from flask import Flask
from spcdados.extensoes import configuration


def minimal_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    configuration.init_app(app)
    return app


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    configuration.init_app(app)
    configuration.load_extensions(app)
    return app
```